# Is there a way to list all non-free software and firmware that is used/installed on my computer?

Tags: 19.04, free-software

As I understand it, Ubuntu uses lots of free (FOSS/FLOSS) software but often also some closed-source proprietary software, which is why Ubuntu is not included in the FSF list of [Free GNU/Linux distributions](https://www.gnu.org/distros/free-distros.html).

While I'm not a fanatic about this, I do want to support the free software movement and use as much free software as possible. So I wonder: is there some way to get a list or overview of all non-free software and firmware that is used/installed on my Ubuntu system?

Answer (score 0):

As you know Aptitude (apt) is a package manager used in Ubuntu . So one can check all installed software and packages with Aptitude.

**apt list --installed**

You can also check with Debian Package Manager(dpkg) with the following command:

**dpkg -l**

***all these commands don't need root/sudo access.***

Comment: This will list all installed packages; not just those made from open-source, but also binary-blobs (ie. not FOSS), eg. your command lists [on my system] "*xubuntu-artwork/eoan,eoan,now 19.10 all [installed]*" but without anything telling me it's open source/FOSS or not. I know that package is; but result doesn't say.